# Can I tune a magnetic field to conduct heat from a rotating object?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

Is there a way to transfer heat from a rotating object made of iron into a suitable heat sink using a magnetic field as a transfer medium?

Comment: Heat can be conducted and convected only.  Without suppling any information about your setup or what you are doing, then the generic answer would be no.

Comment: Magnetic fields can induce electrical currents which can of course create heat, but the only way to transfer energy through a magnetic field is by changing it. Magnetic fields of rotating objects are still constant (unless there is a torque applied to it), you can check this.

Answer (score 2):

Heat can be dissipated using only three mechanisms: conduction (physical contact with a cooler object); convection (physical contact with a cooler gas or liquid); and black body radiation.  In black body radiation, a hot object emits electromagnetic radiation with a wavelength distribution that depends on the object's temperature.  The hotter the object, the shorter the wavelength and the higher the power of the radiation.  But dissipating heat through electromagnetic radiation doesn't sound like what you're looking for.  So the answer is no, there is no way to transfer heat using a magnetic field.